# How to get the current version of Kate and other apps on Kubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, lts, kate

I've been Googling around trying to find a way to get the current version of Kate and KWrite installed on Kubuntu 18.04 and nothing helpful is coming up. Is there some way to override the damn LTS repository for apps like this so they update to current? I can't find a PPA to add for Kate.

Comment: Edit them to WHAT? I know where sources are. I just don't know what to use to get a simple app to install the current version. It's ridiculous.

Comment: **Close voters:** The question is NOT off-topic! We continue to support official flavors for as long as we support the main version. That means that we continue to support the 18.04 flavors until May 2023. Please read this relevant meta question: [How long do we support Ubuntu flavors?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19616/how-long-do-we-support-ubuntu-flavors) (cc: @user535733)

Answer (score 2):

There is some [random PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emutlaqja/+archive/ubuntu/bluez?field.series_filter=bionic) with Kate 19.04, but it provides Kate only for *armhf* and *arm64*, so *amd64* packages [are missed](https://launchpad.net/%7Emutlaqja/+archive/ubuntu/bluez/+packages?field.name_filter=kate&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) here.

---

Also you should know that KDE team provides their packages from [Flatpak](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Flatpak).
So you can install Kate 21.12.2 by using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak xdg-desktop-portal-kde

flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists kdeapps --from https://distribute.kde.org/kdeapps.flatpakrepo
flatpak install kdeapps org.kde.kate
```

Then reboot and find new Kate in the menus. There may be some issues with desktop integration, but they are actually solvable. You may need to remove deb-packaged Kate for example.

Also you can get full list of the available applications by executing `flatpak remote-ls kdeapps` locally. I see 179 applications available with latest versions here.

Comment: Hi. the remote flatpak repo given is for testing versions only ? U have a link for latest stable versions ? Do share.